# Scraping only new data everytime the webscraping program is run

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a web scraping program in python which scrapes a website and saves the data in the database. I want only the new information to be saved in the database when the scraping program is done. Is there any technique/idea to do that? The OS i am using is ubuntu.

Comment: "Yes"? You'll need to narrow down your problem to get a better response. What have you tried? How do you define "new information"? etc.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can look at the response header for a last modified date:

```
In [76]: url = 'http://python.org/ftp/python/3.2.2/Python-3.2.2.tar.bz2'

In [77]: import urllib

In [78]: d = urllib.urlopen(url)

In [79]: dict(d.info())
Out[79]: 
{'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
 'connection': 'close',
 'content-length': '10743647',
 'content-type': 'application/x-bzip2',
 'date': 'Thu, 13 Mar 2014 14:55:47 GMT',
 'etag': '"10c0008-a3ef5f-4ac0c2bd7f180"',
 'last-modified': 'Sat, 03 Sep 2011 16:43:02 GMT',
 'server': 'Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)'}
```

If you store the last_modified date in the database, then you can compare the stored date versus the latest last_modified date to decide if the data should be downloaded again.

Not all response headers include a `last_modified` header, however.

---

Another option is to create a database table with a UNIQUE constraint, and then insert the data with an `INSERT IGNORE` command which would skip the insertion if doing so would violate the UNIQUE constraint. The details of how to do this depends on what database you are using. (Note that [INSERT IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) is MySQL-specific, in `sqlite3` it would be `INSERT OR IGNORE`...).